# Are global variables accessible in Angular 2 html template directly?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So I put in app.settings like

```
public static get DateFormat(): string { return 'MM/DD/YYYY';}
```

and then in one of my html template of a component I want to do something like this.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="Holiday" [date-format]="AppSettings.DateFormat"/>
```

In component I have

```
import { AppSettings } from '../../../app.settings';
```

Right now it's not accessible like this in html template. Is there any way?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, the scope for code in the template is the component instance. You need to assign the value to a field in the component, or add a getter or method that forwards to the global variable in order to be able to use it from the template.

```ts
import { AppSettings } from '../../../app.settings';

...
export class MyComponent {
  get dateFormat() {
    return AppSettings.DateFormat;
  }
}
```

then you can use it like

```ts
<input [(ngModel)]="Holiday" [date-format]="dateFormat"/>
```

Comment: Every time Angular forces me to add another instance variable I get sad.

Answer (score 9):

It seems hacky but you can use pipe. It saves you from repeating injection or variable binding for each component.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'settings',
})
export class GlobalVariablePipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any): object {
        return AppSettings;
    }
}
```

Then, once imported in your module, you can simply use the pipe as follows:

```
{{(''|settings).DateFormat}}
```

Comment: That looks horribly hacky! Some easy improvements imho would be to use `{{ ({} | fillSettings).DateFormat }}` or `{{ 'DateFormat' | fromSettings }}` and maybe the typing can be improved to have type safety

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, no, and that's by design. Templates are hooked up in conjunction with components, that's how they derive their scope and thereby access to bindable data. It's possible it could be hacked around, but even if you figure it out, this is a path you should not follow.

I do this sort of thing with a class:

```
class AppConfig {}

AppConfig.Globals = {
    TEST_VAL: 'hey now here is the value'
};
export { AppConfig }
```

And then use it like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppConfig } from '../../app/app.config';

class HomeComponent {
    constructor() {
        this.test_val = AppConfig.Globals.TEST_VAL;
    }
}

HomeComponent.annotations = [
    new Component ( {
       templateUrl: './views/home/home.component.html'
    } )
];

export { HomeComponent }
```

In the template:

```
{{test_val}}
```

Works well for me.

Comment: Note you could use exported constants in that AppConfig file as well if you're more comfortable with that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems an old topic. However here is my 2 cents. I used a service instead and it's working. I come up with something like this : `<input [(ngModel)]="Holiday" [date-format]="appSettingService.DateFormat"/>`. The inconvenient of this solution, you have DI the service.

Here is what I did :

appSettingService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({

})
    export class AppSettingService{   
      constructor() { }  
      public DateFormat(): string { return 'MM/DD/YYYY';}
...
```

In your component :

```
...
 constructor(public appSettingService : AppSettingService ) { }  
...
```

And finally your in your template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="Holiday" [date-format]="appSettingService.DateFormat"/>
```

I'm looking for a way to use the value without the suffixe like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="Holiday" [date-format]="DateFormat"/>
```

Comment: This is basically the same as the accepted answer. You inject the service here, so it's accessible from the component's scope.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.** Define global json `globals.json`

```
{
  "LABEL": "Your Text"
}
```

**Step 2.** Define Injectable Globals class `globals.ts` and add to providers in `app.module.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import jsonGlobals from './globals.json';

@Injectable()
export class Globals {
  prop: any = jsonGlobals;
}
```

`in app.module.ts`

```
providers: [Globals]
```

**Step 3.** Inject in component's constructor

```
constructor(public globals: Globals) { }
```

**Step 4.** Add following compiler properties in `tsconfig.json`

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

**Step 5.** Use in HTML templates

```
{{globals.prop.LABEL}}
```