# How to use Math.min() or Math.max() syntax in angular template?

Tags: angular

In my pagination component, here is my code below:

```
<p>Showing {{(page-1) * pageSize}} to {{ Math.min((page-1) * pageSize + pageSize,tasks.length)}} of {{tasks.length}}</p>.
```

But it did not works. Can anybody tell what problem it has?

Comment: you will probably need to have a local function in your class which mocks the `min` and `max` functions. or you could try to instantiate `Math` as a local variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your component, you could add `math = Math;`, then in your html, change it to

```
<p>Showing {{(page-1) * pageSize}} to {{ math.min((page-1) * pageSize + pageSize, tasks.length)}} of {{tasks.length}}</p>.
```

This creates a local copy of `Math` without needing to create extra functions and getters

Answer (score 8):

Check the original answer of [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41451435/4953406)

In short: It is not possible to access global variables from within the template files.

You have to at least create a getter that returns global variable.

In your typescript file create a getter called Math

```
get Math() {
  return Math;
}
```

BUT I would either rename it to `math` or create a helper methods in my typescript file

Comment: You are right, I define a customer method and works, but there is no inbuilt method like Math.min() in Typescript?